# trouble with display images file path

Tags: php, mysql, image, echo

I'm working on basic ecommerce project, i'm trying to display image using file path name from mysql and store image file in folder name "image".

I use this code to display image but is not working, is just not showing image... please see the the sample code...

```
/// Gather these full product Information from database /// //////

if ( isset( $_GET['pid'] ) ) {
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id='$targetID' LIMIT 1");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ( $productCount > 0 ) {
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) ) { 
            $product_id = $row["product_id"];
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        $product_detail = $row["product_detail"];
        $product_company = $row["product_company"];
        $screenshot = $row["screenshot"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry dude that crap dont exist.";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Part of this forms i use ....(please see line where it said echo on last line...)

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="edit_company.php">
  <table width="95%" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>

    echo '<td width="36%" rowspan="9" align="right">  <img src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot .'" width="351" height="402" />  </td>';
```

But that last line is not showing image, what did i missed!

Comment: try,  <td width="36%" rowspan="9" align="right">  <img src=<?php echo GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot; ?> width="351" height="402" />  </td>

Comment: define('GW_UPLOADPATH', 'image/');

Comment: <?php  echo '<td width="36%" rowspan="9" align="right">  <img src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot .'" width="351" height="402" />  </td>'; ?>

Comment: 1. Protect your code from SQL injection (e.g. use prepared statements) 2. Use mysqli* instead of the deprecated (and less secure) mysql* functions 3. Try to do some debugging yourself and provide us with more info (e.g. what is the value of GW_UPLOADPATH, what is the value of $screenshot, what is the output HTML etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <img src="<?php echo $GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot ?>" width="351" height="402" />
```